# Want to add "addEventListener" on multiple elements with same class

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener, dom-events, event-listener

I'd like to perform the logic in the "onClick" through the event listener in jS but it only seems to run once? I have the class in all four but I can't figure out why it seems to only work for the first?

HTML:

```
<button id='btn-1' type="button" name="first" class="breakdown main-text" onclick="enableButton('btn-2');disableButton('btn-1');show('btn-1')"> Breakdown Start </button>
<button id='btn-2' type="button" name="second" class="breakdown main-text" onclick="enableButton('btn-3');disableButton('btn-2');show('btn-2')" disabled> Repair Start </button>
<button id='btn-3' type="button" name="third" class="breakdown main-text" onclick="enableButton('btn-4');disableButton('btn-3');show('btn-3')" disabled> Repair End </button>
<button id='btn-4' type="button" name="fourth" class="breakdown main-text" onclick="show('btn-4')" disabled> Breakdown Ended </button>
```

JS:

```
let button1 = document.querySelector('#btn-1')
let button2 = document.querySelector('#btn-2');
let button3 = document.querySelector('#btn-3');
let button4 = document.querySelector('#btn-4');


const breakdownButton = document.querySelector('.breakdown');
breakdownButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
console.log(this.innerHTML);
});
```

Comment: The other buttons are disabled. Event listener for them won't be triggered apart from the first button

Comment: How else would I dynamically disable and re enable the buttons?

Comment: Use [event delegation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_delegation) instead of assigning multiple event listeners — it’s more maintainable. E.g., use an [event argument](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_event_listener_callback)’s [`target`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Event/target). See [the tag info](/tags/event-delegation/info) and [What is DOM Event delegation?](/q/1687296/4642212). Here: `addEventListener("click", ({ target }) => { if(target.closest(".breakdown")){ console.log(target.innerHTML); } });`.

Comment: Related (maybe duplicate): [addEventListener on NodeList](/q/12362256/4642212).

Answer (score 17):

You need to use `querySelectorAll` which will return a collection.Now use `spread operator` (three dots) to convert it to array and use `forEach` .Inside `forEach` callback add the event listener to it

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('.breakdown')].forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(item.innerHTML);
  });
   });
```

```html
<button id='btn-1' type="button" name="first" class="breakdown main-text"> Breakdown Start </button>
<button id='btn-2' type="button" name="second" class="breakdown main-text" disabled> Repair Start </button>
<button id='btn-3' type="button" name="third" class="breakdown main-text" disabled> Repair End </button>
<button id='btn-4' type="button" name="fourth" class="breakdown main-text" disabled> Breakdown Ended </button>
```

In your snippet you have also attached inline event handler,that may not be necessary.

If the objective is to enable the next button then a `function` to enable it can be called from the callback function of the event handler

Comment: Is the spread into an array really necessary? `forEach` can be called on the `querySelectorAll` result in Chrome console it would seem.

Comment: It cannot however be called directly on the result of `getElementsByClassName` unfortunately...

Comment: anyone knows why this works with `querySelectorAll` and does not work with `document.getElementsByClassName` ?

Comment: @S.. Because one returns a [`NodeList`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList), the other an [`HTMLCollection`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). Only one of those has the `forEach` method.

Answer (score 3):

Need to use `querySelectorAll` instead of `querySelector`. And iterate over the list like this.

```
const breakdownButton = document.querySelectorAll('.breakdown');

// It add event listeners for the first button element. 
// you can use forloop or map function to iterate over the list elements
// and here i used breakdownButton[0] as an example.

breakdownButton[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(this.innerHTML);
});
```

Use iterate functions like forEach or map. I used forEach

```
const breakdownButton = document.querySelectorAll('.breakdown');
breakdownButton.forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log();
  });
});
```

Comment: `[0]` doesn't iterate over the list. It just takes the first element in it.

Comment: no like this we need to add event listener for the button elements i given the example.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) for `querySelector`:

> querySelector() returns **the first Element** within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors.

If you want to match more than one element, you'll need to use `querySelectorAll` and, because [it doesn't return a single element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method) **loop** over the result.

Alternatively, you could use [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation).

Comment: thank you! Is one more valuable than the other in certain cases?

Comment: @NakulMalhotra — Benefits of event delegation are explained in detail on the question I linked to.